# Looping through JSON in Javascript and listing as a UL

Tags: javascript, php, json

Here is a snippet of the JSON my PHP script is echoing out:

```
[
    {
        "title": "4th of July",
        "start": "2014-07-04"
    },
    {
        "title": "5th of May",
        "start": "2014-05-05"
    },
    {
        "title": "My Birthday",
        "start": "2014-02-03"
    }
]
```

Im trying to loop through all the events and list them out.
The problem Im having is getting into the deeper section of the data. Can someone help me?

Also what if I was to add an array deeper down? Like this:

```
[
    {
        "title": "4th of July",
        "start": "2014-07-04",
        "activities": [
            "badmitten",
            "tennis"
        ]
    }
]
```

---

Here is what I've tried:

```
$.getJSON("json.json", function(data) {
    var items = [];
    $.each(data, function(key, val) {
        //items.push("<li id='" + key + "'>" + val + "</li>");
    });
    $.each(data, function(obj) {
        $.each(obj, function(key, val) {
            items.push("<li id='" + key + "'>" + val + "</li>");
        });
    });
 });
```

Comment: @Usman Ive tried: `$.getJSON(
                    "json.json",
                    function(data) {
                        var items = [];
                      $.each( data, function(key, val) {
                          //items.push("<li id='" + key + "'>" + val + "</li>");
                      });
                      $.each(data, function(obj) {
                          $.each(obj, function(key, val) {
                              items.push("<li id='" + key + "'>" + val + "</li>");
                          });
                      });
                  }
              );`

Comment: **deeper section of the data.**? and I dont see `activities` in you JSON. Please post your details in question

Comment: @Pilot Like if I was to add the activities like that? How would I also retrieve those?

Comment: @hightekjonathan: What would you want to do with them when you've retrieved them? Just add them as additional `<li>` elements with no `id`s? Sounds like you'll need to add an `if (val instanceof Array) {}` and another `$.each()` loop inside to handle that case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
var data = [
    {
        "title": "4th of July",
        "start": "2014-07-04"
    },
    {
        "title": "5th of May",
        "start": "2014-05-05"
    },
    {
        "title": "My Birthday",
        "start": "2014-02-03"
    }
]

data.forEach(function(d){
  // do whatever to each of the item in the array
  console.log(d.title);
  console.log(d.start);
});
```

for deeper section of the data, just keep drilling down using the same way. Inside the loop above:

```
if(d.activities && d.activites.length > 0){
  d.activities.forEach(function(a){
    console.log(a);
  })
}
```

Hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

A little late, since you've already accepted an answer, but if you want it to be dynamic, you could set up a recursive function, like this:

## [Example](http://jsfiddle.net/5ruqK/1/)

```
function printSection(obj) {
    var items = ['<ul>'];
    $.each(obj, function(key, value) {
        var item = '<li'+ (isNaN(key) ? ' id="'+ key +'"' : '') +'>';
        
        if (value instanceof Object) {
            item += key +':';
            item += printSection(value);
        } else {
            item += value;
        }
        
        item += '</li>';
        items.push(item);
    });
    items.push('</ul>');
    return items.join('');
}
```

This way, you can add further levels of nesting without having to change the output loop.

---

```
$.getJSON('json.json', function(data) {
    var result = [];
    $.each(data, function() {
        result.push(printSection(this));
    });

    $('#result').html(result.join(''));
}
```

Comment: How would I set that up tho using the `$.getJSON();`?